# assigning an unsigned value to integer data type

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I wrote code:

```
int a = -1U;
cout << a;
```

Why the output is -1 not 2^w-1?

As in the case of:

```
long long a = -1U;
cout << a;
```

The output comes out as
4294967295

Comment: Try to enable compiler warnings. You will get the warning about possible integer overflow.

Comment: `2^w-1` is outside the range of  `int a`.

Comment: Check what the range of int is. It’s not what you think it is. And assigning -1u to long long will fail any code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1U` is the negation of `1U`.  As an `unsigned` cannot have a negative value the result is incremented by `(UINT_MAX + 1)`.  Result `UINT_MAX` is 4294967295 on OP's machine.

In both of OP's cases, code is initializing a signed integer variable with 4294967295u.

---

```
int a = -1U;
```

> Why the output is -1 not 2^w-1?

2<sup>w</sup> - 1 (`w` being the bit width 32) is outside the range of `int a` so `a` cannot have that value.

Assigning an out-of-range value to an `int` results in implementation defined behavior.  On OP's machine, assigning 4294967295 to an `int` "wrapped" to -1.

---

```
long long a = -1U;
```

`long long a = -1U;` is like `long long a = 4294967295;` (see above), so `a` has the value of 4294967295, well within the `long long` range.

Comment: How is it (UINT_MAX +1), Shouldn't it be -1?

Comment: @BitthalMaheshwari "How is it (UINT_MAX +1), Shouldn't it be -1?" -->  "it"  (`-1U`) is not `(UINT_MAX +1)`.  `-1U` is like -1 **incremented** by `(UINT_MAX +1)`.  `-1 + (UINT_MAX +1) --> UINT_MAX`.  "Shouldn't it be -1" --> the "it` (`-1U`) is an `unsigned` constant.  `unsigned` objects cannot have a negative value like -1.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -1U is unary operator minus applied to unsigned  1U. C++ integral literals do not have sign. See its parsing rules.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Re: "-1U is unary operator minus applied to unsigned 1U.", This answer starts with "-1U is the negation of 1U", so that is already covered.

Comment: @BitthalMaheshwari Parsing of literals and assignment to variables both occur the same way for *unsigned* types: If a positive integral value/literal is too large for the type it is assigned as *value % 2^bitWidth* (`^` interpreted as power, not XOR as in the language) – which means truncating the surplus most significant bits. For negative values *2^bitWidth* is add as many times as necessary to get the value into the range of the type – nice on two's complement, as this is identity (or again just cutting surplus MSB off). This processing for unsigned types is mandated by the standard.